# How to change this text color in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, text, colors

I've been using Netbeans for a long time, but I still find it hard to change text colors in the editor, on top of that I just encountered a new problem, my Java code colors looked fine in older Nb versions, but in the latest version 7.3 they don't look right, please see the attached images for details. I highlighted the text in the second image so we can see the text.

So my questions are :

[a] How to change the text "request" and "response" colors in the following image from black to white ?

[b] Is there a way in NB to right click on the text and change it's foreground/background color ? If none exists, can I suggest this feature for future versions ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Tools -> Options` then to `Fonts and Colors` tab.

[a] For the javadoc parameters, select Java Language from the dropdown menu. It is the `Javadoc Tag`.

[b] For the selection, `Highlighting` tab and `Selected Text` Option.

Answer (score 0):

Update for part A of this question. NetBeans uses "Javadoc Identifier" to format the "request" and "response" you highlighted in the first screenshot. This is still accessed through

> Tools --> Options --> Fonts&Colors --> Syntax --> "Language: Java".